# avoid tooltip from hide on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i dont want to hide my tooltip when mouse is on tooltip.but it should hide we mouse out from tooltip .please help me to do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('[rel=tooltip]').bind('mouseover', function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('ajax')) {
      var ajax = $(this).attr('ajax');  

      $.get(ajax, function(theMessage) {
        $('<div class="tooltip">'  + theMessage + '</div>').appendTo('body').fadeIn('fast');
      });
    }
    else {
      var theMessage = $(this).attr('content');
      $('<div class="tooltip">' + theMessage + '</div>').appendTo('body').fadeIn('fast');
    }

    $(this).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
      $('div.tooltip').css({
        'top': e.pageY - ($('div.tooltip').height() / 2) - 5,
          'left': e.pageX + 15
      });
    });
  }).bind('mouseout', function() {
    $('div.tooltip').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
  });
});
```

Corresponding (trimmed) HTML, formatted vertically here to show the attributes more clearly:

```
<a href="#"
   alt="Image"
   tooltip=""
   rel="tooltip"
   content="&lt;div id=imagcon&gt;&lt;img src=img/1.jpg class=tooltip-image/&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
>View Sonic</a>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: <a href="#" alt="Image" tooltip="" rel="tooltip" content="&lt;div id=imagcon&gt;&lt;img src=img/1.jpg class=tooltip-image/&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=con&gt;2 bhk &lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=con&gt;Villa&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=con&gt;Area:15000.Sq-ft&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=con&gt; Dealer :Amitabh ranjan &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div id=con&gt; &lt;a href=# &gt; View All Details &lt;/a&gt;   &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
  &lt;div id=con&gt; &lt;a href=# &gt; &lt;img src='Dealer/images/email.png' style='width:15px;height:15px' /&gt; Contact Advertiser &lt;/a&gt;   &lt;/div&gt;
 ">View Sonic</a>

Comment: Paste the HTML code into your post, not the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is remove the `mouseout` from the `target` and instead you can bind the mousout event from the tooltip div `div.tooltip`:

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').bind('mouseover', function(){
   ...........
});

Then add this way:

$(document).on('mouseout click', 'div.tooltip', function(){
    $('div.tooltip').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    }); 

});
```

[**Checkout the demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Eg3/)

Comment: i tried this not working :(...this time div is not hiding on click also.i want to hide that div on click

Comment: @deepak see you can place multiple events if using `.on()` jQuery method. see the updates.

Comment: worked for me see the fiddle link !!! In your case you can find browser's console for errors.

Comment: in my browser console throwing this error...                                        Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @deepak if you can upgrade your jQuery library to `1.9+`, then it will work, although i used `1.10` in the fiddle example posted.

Comment: thanks friend it worked finaly...